# How to return 301 redirects for many resources after a site restructure?

Tags: html

I am re-building an old website, and it has many files, which have been moved into a more suitable directory on the server. So obviously, all the url's that Google had of those pages will return a 404 because they're just not there anymore. But I want Google (and others) to know that those pages still exist, and which directory they exist in.

But how do we do that for many different pages?

Comment: Now it is 302 ;) Nice title ;):P

Comment: And coming to your question,if i were u,i'd redirect all those old links to a page which shows the location of new directory.

Comment: What server or what software do you have? Bhuvan Rikka gave you few answers, but you might be a little more precise.

Comment: There are probably many answers for the same problem in the 'Related' section - just to the right ->

Comment: I apologize for the delay everyone, my net crapped out. I'm reading over the answers now. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to redirect the old links to your new domain. This is how you can do it.

**Using php:**

```
<?
 Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
 Header( "Location: http://www.new-url.com" );
?>
```

**Using asp.net:**

```
<script runat="server">
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
 Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
 Response.AddHeader("Location","http://www.new-url.com");
 }
</script>
```

**Using ROR:**

```
def old_action
headers["Status"] = "301 Moved Permanently"
redirect_to "http://www.new-url.com/"
end
```

**Using htaccess**:

Create a .htaccess file with the below code, it will ensure that all your directories and pages of your old domain will get correctly redirected to your new domain.
The .htaccess file needs to be placed in the root directory of your old website (i.e the same directory where your index file is placed)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Please REPLACE www.newdomain.com in the above code with your actual domain name.

In addition to the redirect I would suggest that you contact every backlinking site to modify their backlink to point to your new website.

**Note:** This .htaccess method of redirection works ONLY on Linux servers having the Apache Mod-Rewrite moduled enabled.

Refer [this](http://www.webconfs.com/how-to-redirect-a-webpage.php/) for more methods

Answer (score 1):

Are you running any kind of server side request processing (ie php, asp(.net), java, ruby, etc)?  If so, you could make a lookup dictionary that contains old locations and their new equivalents.  Check all incoming requests if they are in that dictionary and return an appropriate response.

Example in ASP.NET (this goes in Globabl.asax):

```
Private redirectedResourceList As New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {
    {"/files/myfile.txt", "/newfiles/myfile.txt"},
    {"/files/myfile2.txt", "/newfiles/myfile2.txt"}
}

Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If redirectedResourceList.ContainsKey(HttpContext.Current.Request.Path) Then
        Response.StatusCode = 301
        Response.AddHeader("Location", redirectedResourceList(HttpContext.Current.Request.Path))
        Response.End()
    End If
End Sub
```